# Clearing space between two divs

Tags: html

Could anyone please help me with the following problem?
How can I clear the space between div "top" and div "middle"? This is just a portion of my HTML code. In the browser, I can see a white space between the two divs. How can get rid of the space?

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="top">

        </div>

        <div class="middle">

        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what is the css properties for those classes, `.container`, `.top` and `.middle`?

Comment: Please, have a look at the section on [ask] a good question, if you posted a [mcve] it would make it easier to find out what can be the problem, then we could give you better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use flexbox in the container class to achieve this:

```
<style>
    .container {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    .top {
        width: 100px;
        height: 50px;
        background-color: red;
    }

    .middle {
        width: 100px;
        height: 50px;
        background-color: red;
    }
</style>
<div class="container">
    <div class="top">
        <p>Top</p>
    </div>

    <div class="middle">
        <p>Middle</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

[with flexbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0yuK.png)

[without flexbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEB4U.png)

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution I've used before but it's very hacky and usually means that somewhere else you're making a mistake (bad css, poor html markup, etc.)

If you give a `font-size: 0;` to the container element it will render the "space" between the divs at a font size of 0 which will close the gap.

However this can affect font sizes in the child elements within `.container`.

Like I said, you probably have CSS rules elsewhere that can be improved to prevent you from using this hack.

But this should remove the white space on the page that occurs from the whitespace in the gap.

```
.container {
    font-size: 0;
}
```

---

Edit:
[Flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) can usually help with responsive and fluid layouts that will prevent issues like these.

Comment: thank you for your help. When I do font-size: 0, it works but everything disappears (pictures, paragraphs etc...)

Comment: The second option with (display: flex and flex-direction: column;) is working very fine and I just have to do few adjustments. Thank you very much very. You're the bossman!

Answer (score 0):

"*I can see a white space between the two divs.*"

Without all the code, or a screen shot, it's not obvious what this means.

If the whitespace is vertically separating the two divs, then you can reduce or eliminate the margins:

```
.container div { margin: 0; }
```

That style addition would also reduce the whitespace between two horizontally separated divs.

But if you want to totally remove the whitespace, then remove the space from your source:

```
<div class="top">
    ...
</div><div class="middle">  <!-- change here -->
    ...
</div>
```

I.e. there is now no space between the "/div" and "div" tags.

Comment: using .container div{margin: 0} will apply to all your code removing margin everywhere which is not a good idea. You'll have to go fix the margin everywhere it's been reset to 0. But the flex option above works the best.